# Internet explorer keeps Flash objects in memory and slow performance

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, memory

Couple of questions here, please check out this link

http://dev.garage.a2om.com/modules/v2/FSI_VideoTest/en-US/index.html?returnUrl=http://garage.a2om.com/moduleViewer/default.aspx

if you click next - wait for the videos to load (They are all the same) then it works fine.

However, look at your PCs memory, and you will see that it grows a lot with each page. It doesn't do this in the other browsers.

I am guessing that IE is not releasing the memory from the active x object when its "removed"

I am using the jquery remove() method to remove the object.

I have also tried JS delete and null, same effects.

Any idea how to properly free up that memory?

The next issue, is that because the flash active X takes so long to render, if you spam "next" and "previous" a few times, it leads to very undesirable results. Somtimes the flash doesn't display, but the audio plays, sometimes the video will play with another audio stream in the background - and generally, skipping pages is horrible and slow.

Any ideas on how to speed this up? Is it something we will have to live with?

Thanks in advance, let me know if there is any code you want to look at/have info on.